# Setting/unsetting terms using the Backbone JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, rest-api, backbone

I'd like to set and delete terms in my custom taxonomy using the [WordPress Backbone JavaScript client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/), which provides access to the REST API in JavaScript.

I can't find an example or suggestion in the documentation about how to add and delete terms in my custom taxonomy. I have verified that the taxonomy itself is shown in the client - I can load it using

```
var taxonomy = new wp.api.models.My_custom_taxonomy().fetch();
```

where `My_custom_taxonomy` is created by the JavaScript client by inspecting the REST API. I can verify that `taxonomy` contains useful information by inspecting it in my console. For example, `taxonomy.responseJSON` contains an array with the description, ID, link to the REST API endpoint, etc. for my taxonomy - so that part is working. But can I set and delete terms in this taxonomy via the JavaScript client?